# calculate calories on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i develop a application that finde the distance between the two points and calculate the speed but we require the calories burn after walk this distance. that i measure it.

---

I am developing an application that finds the distance between two points and calculates the speed of movement between these points. We require the number of calories burnt after walking this distance. How do I measure it?

Comment: This might help: http://www.google.com/search?q=calories+burnt+when+walking

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty off topic and would be better answered by a dietist/nutritionist, but besides the distance and the speed, the biggest factor is the person's weight.

For the constants in the equation, I suggest you just [google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=calories+burned+walking) and try to decide what works best for you.